# Can you use Redux with Ionic/React?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, redux

Pretty simple question. I have a very basic React/Redux/Node login system. If I convert it into a mobile application by using Ionic, will the Redux functionality still work? Or are they incompatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally possible to use both, I can't see why it would be limited to be honest.

By searching on Google, you can find already lots of resources about this

[Ionic React and Redux](https://bendyworks.com/blog/ionic-react-and-redux)

[Adding Redux to an Ionic application](https://www.javascripttuts.com/adding-redux-to-an-ionic-application/)